# В WebView не открывается выпадающий список

Tags: java, android

Суть проблемы такова:
Есть сайт в котором можно загружать фотографии и в выпадающем списке выбирать категорию загруженных фото.

Если я использую стандартное создание webView через layout, то все работает, нажимается и загружается

Но стоит мне создать webView программно, как фотки грузит, но сам список становится некликабельным.

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду под "отрисовка стандартная и программно"?

Comment: Тут я прошу прощение, не совсем правильно написал. Я создаю вью указывая его в разметке xml. Во втором варианте добавляю его в разметку в активити